# Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method on codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, email, smtp

i would like to create reset password by sending email but the problem is

**"The following SMTP error was encountered: 
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method."**

I am using webmail account of my domainand  I am not using phpmailer

here is my controller

```
                $config['protocol']  = "smtp";
                $config['smtp_host'] = "mail.domain.co.id";
                $config['smtp_port'] = "587";
                $config['smtp_user'] = "user@domain.co.id";
                $config['smtp_pass'] = "xxxxxxx"; 
                $config['charset']   = "iso-8859-1";
                $config['mailtype']  = "text";
                $config['newline']   = "\r\n";
                $config['mailpath']  = "/usr/bin/sendmail";

                $this->email->initialize($config);
                $this->email->from('user@domain.co.id', 'System');
                $this->email->to(otheruser@domain.co.id);
                $this->email->subject('Reset Password');

                $this->email->message("Message");

                if (!$this->email->send()) {
                    echo $this->email->print_debugger();
                    exit;
                }
```

my sendmail.conf in xampp

```
smtp_server=mail.domain.co.id
smtp_port=587
smtp_ssl=auto
auth_username=user@domain.co.id
auth_password=xxxxxxx
;default_domain=domain.co.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of $this->email->initialize($config); you should load the library after specifying the config variable $this->load->library('email',$config); --worked for me.